# Disable automatic "Updating projects..." action in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using a quite large project in Eclipse, composed by different libraries which can be build independently thanks to dedicated "Make Target" elements.
When compiling one of this libraries, the compilation works fine, but afterwards, Eclipse keeps busy by doing "Building Targets. Updating projects..."  (as named in the Progress View).  As my project is rather large, this action takes several minutes, preventing me to start new compilations or change Eclipse settings.
Is there any way to disable this automatic update in Eclipse?

I have observed this behaviour in Eclipse Helios and Eclipse Juno.

---

I have tried to remove my "Make target" objects, and give an invalid C/C++ Build configuration (e.g., provide an invalid make command).
As expected, when building the project, Eclipse tries to execute the invalid make command (which fails), but then keeps doing this "Updating projects..." anyway...

Comment: I never found a solution for this apart from filtering resources in the project configuration so there is less element to refresh after a build...

Comment: Indeed, but that's not enough in my case.  I wonder why any other update (indexing, refreshing) can be disabled and executed manually, but this update (I don't actually now *what* is really being updated) is forced.

Answer (score 0):

After build Eclipse is looking for newly created executables. If your project is Makefile-based Eclipse cannot be sure where to search and browses the whole source tree.
Assuming your executable are all go into a folder bin-XXX, you can reduce these searches as following:

1. Select the top project (say "src") and go to the right-menu dialog “Properties” (alternatively: top menu Project-Properties). Then go to “C++ build”-“Refresh policy”. Here select the folder “src” and press “Add Exception”. Then add all folders except “bin-XXX” as an exception.
2. Select the top project “src” and go to the right-menu dialog “Properties” (alternatively: top menu Project-Properties). Then go to “C++ General – Paths and Symbols – Output Location”. Add folder “bin-XXX” and remove the folder “src”