# Eclipse Mars Background Process Issue

Tags: java, eclipse

Started up eclipse today and for some reason it was having an issue with completing the background process(Stuck at 6%) of updating one of my projects. Ive tried a couple different options from letting it be for hours or tried to stop it. No luck so far. Anyone have a clue on how I can fix this? It was working 100% the day before.. Picture is:

[image]

**Things I've tried**

1. disabled autobuild
2. restarted pc as well as eclipse many times
3. attempt to hit stop process, but it would result in a frozen eclipse.

Comment: Can you tell us any more details about the project or your setup? List out everything that you have tried so far.

Comment: updated on what Ive tried.

Comment: Also it was a javafx project, with a traditional setup. Nothing fancy or out the normal. Scene builder was also being used. Another thing that its just one of these projects that is as stated above. The rest are your traditional java projects.

Comment: Did this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876380/disable-automatic-updating-projects-action-in-eclipse-cdt

The question above hasn't accepted this as an answer, but just curious if this works for you or no.

Comment: Thank you I attempted it but no luck. Still getting this darn updating. Ive noticed if I create a new workspace and import my projects there I havent got an issue yet. Whatever it is its definitely something to do with the certain projects. I believe it may of even come from this recent java update I have done.

Comment: Please wait a bit. Sometimes it requires time to finish the downloading tasks.

Comment: Waited 2 days. If thats not patience then I dont know what is lol.

Comment: try to close the project and then reopen it.